# Split a string by a one-char delimiter in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have seen some very popular questions here, on StackOverflow about splitting a string in C++, but every time, they needed to split that string by the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> delimiter. Instead, I want to split an `std::string` by the <kbd>;</kbd> delimiter.

This code is taken from a n answer on StackOverflow, but I don't know how to update it for <kbd>;</kbd>, instead of <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    string sentence = "And I feel fine...";
    istringstream iss(sentence);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: There are answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Read about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: You can create your own iterator which wraps around `std::getline(in >> std::ws, part, ';')`.

Comment: Actually, the answer you took your code from is right above (when ordered by votes) an answer that splits it with any delimiter.

Comment: You can find different solutions and explanations here: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the answers from [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c?rq=1) that uses any delimiter.

I use this to split string by a delim. The first puts the results in a pre-constructed vector, the second returns a new vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

Note that this solution does not skip empty tokens, so the following will find 4 items, one of which is empty:

```
std::vector<std::string> x = split("one:two::three", ':');
```